# Regular Expression match lines starting with a certain character OR whitespace and then that character

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches lines beginning with a hyphen (-) OR that begins with spaces or tabs and then has a hyphen. So it should match the following:

```
- hello!
            - hello!
```

Here's what I've got so far: `^(\-)`. But that doesn't match the second example above because it requires the first character to be a hyphen.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can try

```
^\s*-
```

- `^`: start of string
- `\s*`: zero or more whitespace characters
- `-`: a literal `-` (you don't need to escape this outside a character class)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this regex by making 0 or more spaces optional match at beginning:

```
^\s*-
```

Comment: There could be more than one whitespace character at the front, according to the example.

Answer (score 1):

the above (using \s*) is the easiest one for this case, but in general, you can always use the | syntax:

```
re.match('^-|^\s+-', '- hello')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000054E72030>

re.match('^-|^\s+-', '     - hello')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000054E72030>

re.match('^-|^\s+-', '     + hello')
None
```

`^-` is the case for - at beginning, `^\s+-' is with one or more spaces, and | chooses either one.

Comment: But why would you ever do this when you have `\s*`?

Comment: you wouldn't in this case, but because of the way the question is worded, could also lean towards a general question about matching this OR that, which this specific solution wouldn't address. anyways, for his specific problem, yours is a simpler solution.