# How to replace a single character and not affect the occurence of the character in a full word?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have extracted words from a PDF and I noticed that bullet points get converted to `o`.

**Original text:**

[image]

**Extracted text(`o` does not start at the beginning of a line I just formatted it for readability):**

```
o Organize and coordinate ad hoc task forces for specific topics based on demand from AFR100 countries o Keep document repository for AFR100 including documentation of focal points, pledge and affiliation documents, progress information from countries, etc. o Treatment of demands from countries and identification of potential technical partners to assist together with the support of the MT
```

So I am wondering how do I remove the `o` only when it is not in a word?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression match lines starting with a certain character OR whitespace and then that character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274493/regular-expression-match-lines-starting-with-a-certain-character-or-whitespace-a)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the question that the ```o``` does not begin at a line.

Comment: Where does it begin then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
txt = '''
o Organize and coordinate ad hoc task forces for specific topics based on demand from AFR100 countries
o Keep document repository for AFR100 including documentation of focal points, pledge and affiliation documents, progress information from countries, etc.
o Treatment of demands from countries and identification of potential technical partners to assist together with the support of the MT
'''

import re

txt = re.sub(r'\bo\b', '', txt)

print(txt)
```

Output:

```
 Organize and coordinate ad hoc task forces for specific topics based on demand from AFR100 countries
 Keep document repository for AFR100 including documentation of focal points, pledge and affiliation documents, progress information from countries, etc.
 Treatment of demands from countries and identification of potential technical partners to assist together with the support of the MT
```

The `\b` in the regex is a word-boundary, so, look for an `o` with one word boundary on each side, i.e. a word that consists of one occurrence of `o`.

Comment: This will also replace an `o` in the middle of the text ("o lord"...). Better to only match it at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I formatted the text to make it easier to read but actually the ```o``` does not start at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @yuRa So how is it? Is it always on a new line preceded by some spaces? Or could it be somewhere in the middle of a line.

Comment: I have edited the text in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: In that case, unless there's a pattern, you can use my regex, there aren't that many uses of `o` as an independent _term_ even in literary writing, and I assume this pdf is technical, so you can assume that if an `o` is independent, it is a bullet point, and remove it safely.