# I have to validate the input type="text" name( full name of the employee) in Reactive Form with white space not allowed at starting

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

## **app.component.html**

I have make a form with userData with many fields and I validate it.

```
 <div class="form-group mb-3">
          <label for="fname" class="control-label"><span style="color:red">*</span>Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control p-2 my-2" placeholder="First name" formControlName="fname">
          <span class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="userData.controls['fname'] && userData.controls['fname'].touched && userData.controls['fname'].invalid">Please
            Input Valid Name</span>
        </div>
```

## **app.component.ts**

But I want a validation which gave error message and being invalid if any user insert blank value or white spaces at starting. But there, white spaces allowed between firstName and lastName

```
userData = new FormGroup({
    fname: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]+$')]),
```

})

I have tried this validation for whitespaces but it also allowed spaces at starting.

```
userData = new FormGroup({
    fname: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]+$')]),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First regex example you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19274518/4472932). Second option: Remove whitespace (better user experience) with `.trim()`.

Greetings, Flo